# SQL: How can i run nested Stored Procedures and return multiple values

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, nested

I've been trying to run a procedure like this:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[GetViewData]
AS
IF EXISTS( SELECT * FROM dbo.CONFIG )
BEGIN
    DECLARE @count as INTEGER
    SET @count = (select count(Id) FROM dbo.CONFIG)
    DECLARE @TimeFrom as DATETIME
    DECLARE @TimeTo as DATETIME
    DECLARE @unit as INTEGER
    WHILE (@count >= 1)
    BEGIN
        SET @TimeFrom = (select TimeStampFrom from CONFIG where Id = @count);
        SET @TimeTo = (select TimeStampTo from CONFIG where Id = @count);
        SET @unit = (select Unit from CONFIG where Id = @count);
        EXECUTE dbo.GetDataSet @Timestampfrom = @timeFrom,@TimestampTo = @timeTo, @Unit = @unit;
        SET @count = @count - 1;
    END
END
```

The return value is the correct number og tables, but all tables are empty. And when i run the internal procedure on its own, it recives correct values(one table filled with data).
The internal procedure in the post looks like this.

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[GetDataSet]
@Timestampfrom DATETIME,
@TimestampTo DATETIME,
@Unit INTEGER
AS
select
DATA.Unit,
DATA.CO2Data,
DATA.HumidData,
DATA.TempData,
DATA.TimeStamp
from DATA where Unit = @Unit and TimeStamp between @Timestampfrom and @TimestampTo;
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific.)

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio 2017

Comment: What does "all tables are empty" mean?   How are you seeing these empty tables?

Comment: You are not storing the internal procedure's result anywhere. This will just do a SELECT N times.

Comment: There is no guarantee there will be an ID = count(Id).  A cursor would be a better tool for this.  I am not seeing any command that would fill a table with data.

Comment: So, do i have to store the result on each call, then return the result ? In which case, how do i do this. I've seen examples online for how to do it with a defined number of tables to return. But this code will return a variable amount of tables depending on the amount of rows in CONFIG.

Comment: The tables are empty in the sense that, when i execute this procedure in my dbms, then the result are multiple tables that contain the right columns as the ones i would expect, but there is no data in any of the cells.

Answer (score 1):

A solution would be creating a temporary table in the outmost procedure and insert the result in the innermost one.

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[GetViewData] AS

IF EXISTS( SELECT * FROM dbo.CONFIG )
BEGIN

    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#DataSetResult') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE #DataSetResult

    CREATE TABLE #DataSetResult (
        Unit VARCHAR(100),
        CO2Data VARCHAR(100),
        HumidData VARCHAR(100),
        TempData VARCHAR(100),
        TimeStamp DATETIME)

    DECLARE @count INT = (select count(Id) FROM dbo.CONFIG)

    DECLARE @TimeFrom as DATETIME
    DECLARE @TimeTo as DATETIME
    DECLARE @unit as INTEGER

    WHILE (@count >= 1)
    BEGIN

        SET @TimeFrom = (select TimeStampFrom from CONFIG where Id = @count);
        SET @TimeTo = (select TimeStampTo from CONFIG where Id = @count);
        SET @unit = (select Unit from CONFIG where Id = @count);

        EXECUTE dbo.GetDataSet 
            @Timestampfrom = @timeFrom,
            @TimestampTo = @timeTo, 
            @Unit = @unit;

        SET @count = @count - 1;
    END

    -- Display results
    SELECT * FROM #DataSetResult AS D

END

GO


ALTER procedure [dbo].[GetDataSet]
    @Timestampfrom DATETIME,
    @TimestampTo DATETIME,
    @Unit INTEGER
AS
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO #DataSetResult (
        Unit,
        CO2Data,
        HumidData,
        TempData,
        TimeStamp)
    select
        DATA.Unit,
        DATA.CO2Data,
        DATA.HumidData,
        DATA.TempData,
        DATA.TimeStamp
    from 
        DATA 
    where 
        Unit = @Unit and 
        TimeStamp between @Timestampfrom and @TimestampTo;
END
```

If you can't change the innermost procedure, you will have to do an `INSERT INTO EXEC`, which isn't recommended as your can't nest several ones.

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[GetViewData] AS

IF EXISTS( SELECT * FROM dbo.CONFIG )
BEGIN

    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#DataSetResult') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE #DataSetResult

    CREATE TABLE #DataSetResult (
        Unit VARCHAR(100),
        CO2Data VARCHAR(100),
        HumidData VARCHAR(100),
        TempData VARCHAR(100),
        TimeStamp DATETIME)

    DECLARE @count INT = (select count(Id) FROM dbo.CONFIG)

    DECLARE @TimeFrom as DATETIME
    DECLARE @TimeTo as DATETIME
    DECLARE @unit as INTEGER

    WHILE (@count >= 1)
    BEGIN

        SET @TimeFrom = (select TimeStampFrom from CONFIG where Id = @count);
        SET @TimeTo = (select TimeStampTo from CONFIG where Id = @count);
        SET @unit = (select Unit from CONFIG where Id = @count);

        INSERT INTO #DataSetResult (
            Unit,
            CO2Data,
            HumidData,
            TempData,
            TimeStamp)
        EXECUTE dbo.GetDataSet 
            @Timestampfrom = @timeFrom,
            @TimestampTo = @timeTo, 
            @Unit = @unit;

        SET @count = @count - 1;
    END

    -- Display results
    SELECT * FROM #DataSetResult AS D

END
```

Please review the result set data types, as I put `VARCHAR` for most of them.

Comment: I tried it, and then it just returned one table with no data(one empty table) instead of many empty tables. I want it to return many tables, but i know that they should contain data. So when no tables return with data, that makes me confused...

Comment: If you are expecting an N amount of tables as result and you get less than that, the problem is on your while loop conditions. If you expect the table to return results and they don't (they come up empty) the problem is on your select's filtering conditions and parameters. Either way, the solution I gave is to return all results into 1 table, which I thought you needed. Use PRINT to check the values you are passing as parameter to your inner SP (inside the loop) and check if they are correct.